# Grouped ggplot bars with a gradient color dependent on another variable

Tags: r, colors, ggplot2

My dataset includes values for 'left' and 'right' of 8 (4x2) observations. Like this TEST frame:

```
Labels        r         pval      Mean  Side
L1 0.49425792 1.191802e-04 0.7992786  Left
L2 0.25906498 3.371854e-02 1.7977923  Left
L3 0.63098789 3.711588e-07 0.8519239  Left
L4 0.20325181 7.707517e-02 1.1287030  Left
L1 0.72761384 7.991909e-10 1.1369230  Right
L2 0.93941231 0.000000e+00 1.0262915  Right
L3 0.80899301 3.805845e-13 1.1670454  Right
L4 0.30345181 7.507517e-02 1.1677030  Right
```

and I can create a grouped plot doing:

```
ggplot(data = TEST, aes(factor(Labels),r, fill=Side)) + 
geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "dodge")
```

The plot is very nice and I can see 'Left/Right' grouped for each label. However, I would like to use a gradient color to fill each bar using the values in 'Mean', keeping the grouped 'Left/Right' bars.

Is it possible to do that?
Thank you,
Fab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `group` statement based on Side and specify `fill` according to Mean:

```
ggplot(data = TEST, aes(factor(Labels),r, group=Side, fill=Mean)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "dodge")
```

If you want to change the colours you can add `scale_fill_gradient()`, e.g.

```
scale_fill_gradient(low="blue", high="red")
```

[image]

Comment: Nice!Would be possible to use a differente gradient color for "Left" and "Right" group?Thank you!Fab

Comment: For example, adding "col=Side", like: ggplot(data = TEST, aes(factor(Sulci),ICC, group =Side, fill=Mean, col = Side)) + 
    geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "dodge") will add additional lines to the bars to distinguish between "Left" and "Right", which is already good. Is there a way to assign different gradients?One for "Left" (blue, red) and one for "Right" (yellow,green)? Thank you!Fab

Comment: @user3306909 unfortunately I can't think of a way to do that. You could ask a new question though.

Comment: how about filling gradient of bars from left to right... e.g. left side histograms with red color, right side with green color... ?? `ggplot(data = comb, aes(comb$Sentiment_Score)) + 
  geom_histogram(col="black", aes(fill=..count.., alpha=0.5)) +
  scale_fill_gradient("Count", low = "red", high = "green")`